# How mimic a pivot and then apply text join in a single formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with multiple values and categorizations, I want to calculate the total sum for each category and then create a row that displays each category with its total value. I tried combining, unique with `sumif` and `textjoin` but could not get it to work.

The below is what I'm after.

e.g. Say I have the table FRUIT_SALES

| Fruit Type | Seller | No. Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banana | Fresh Grocer | 40 |
| Banana | Big Seller | 20 |
| Banana | Farm stall | 50 |
| Apple | Juicer | 400 |
| Apple | Farm stall | 10 |

I want to use single formula to generate a table summarised by fruit.

eg.

| Fruit Type | No. Sold |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 410 |
| Banana | 110 |

I've used unique list the fruit type, and sum if to calculate the number sold but I want this in a single formula so I can then turn it into the below text using a text join.

"Apple (410), Banana (110)"

My final formula would include another parameter, but if I can Get from FRUIT_SALES to "Apple 410), Banana (110)" it will give me the base of what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LET` function to do this:

```
=LET(fruits, UNIQUE(FRUIT_SALES[Fruit Type]), sales, SUMIFS(FRUIT_SALES[No. Sold], FRUIT_SALES[Fruit Type], fruits), TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, fruits & " (" & sales & ")"))
```

[image]

`fruits` represents every possible value in the fruit column. By passing it to the third argument of the `SUMIFS`, you create an array of the same size as the `fruit` array, that contains the sum for each fruit.

The formula `fruit & sales` simply concatenates the nth value of the fruit array with the nth value of the sales array. Which creates another array of the same size.

The rest is just a matter of using `TEXTJOIN` with this concatenated array and adding some formatting.

If you want to customise further:

- Add the function `SORT` or `FILTER` to the `fruits` variable, in order to sort or filter the list of fruits (for example if you want to filter by customer).
- Use the function `TEXT` to format the `sales` values. It's useful to deal with decimals or show the thousand separator. You can also add a `ROUND` in front of the `SUMIFS` to remove decimals.

Here is an example with the `FILTER` function:

```
=LET(fruits, UNIQUE(FILTER(FRUIT_SALES[Fruit Type], FRUIT_SALES[Seller]=$B$11)), sales, SUMIFS(FRUIT_SALES[No. Sold],FRUIT_SALES[Fruit Type], fruits, FRUIT_SALES[Seller],$B$11), TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, fruits & " ("&sales&")"))
```

[image]

To generate the intermediary summary table, you can use the following function:

```
=LET(fruits, UNIQUE(FRUIT_SALES[Fruit Type]), sales, SUMIFS(FRUIT_SALES[No. Sold],FRUIT_SALES[Fruit Type], fruits), HSTACK(VSTACK("Fruit Type", fruits), VSTACK("Sales", sales)))
```

[image]