# How to add commas to a number using an excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a fairly complicated formula that concatenates a series of text strings and numbers.  After looking at the result I realised that I need to format some of the numbers in the formula. I want to add comma Seperators to the number.  How do I do that using a formula that can work with arrays.

e.g I have

| Current values | Preferred values |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 10,000 |
| 202222 | 202,222 |

Note this cannot be done using the standard formatting because it based on a complex that sums values and concatenates text.  An example of the type of formula can be found in this question: [How mimic a pivot and then apply text join in a single formula in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1821782/how-mimic-a-pivot-and-then-apply-text-join-in-a-single-formula-in-excel/1821795#1821795)

Comment: Is a formula necessary? Why not use number formatting?

Comment: Because the output is a concatenation between text and number results, it generates a string like this Category1(1324), Category2(3534), Category3(3423223).  There are multiple rows generated like this.

I've updated the qeustion based on this comment, so thanks.

Comment: Let assume A2's value is 10000, try the following formula in A3 `=TEXT(A2,"#,###")`. You can adapt the formula to fit with the complex formula by swapping A2 with the complex formula.

Comment: Would that work If i dont know the number of digits, e.g. it could be a 4 digit number it could be a 7 digit number?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I just tested it out and it work, that should have been an answer not a comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the following formula:

```
=TEXT(A2,"#,###")
```

For example, if your complex formula was `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2,A3)`, then the formula will be:

```
=TEXT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2,A3),"#,###")
```

[image]

Comment: The first argument in `TEXT` function must be a number or a text convertable to number, not any text. So your formula should be: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXT(A2,"#,###"),A3)`

Comment: @MGonet The TEXTJOIN part is just a place holder for the OP to understand that the A2 can be replace with his/her own formula, not intended to be used as is although I fully understand your point. `TEXT` function should (hopefully) work as the OP stated in the comments: ...Because the output is a concatenation between text and number results.

Comment: For note I used it the otherway aroud,  e.g. TextJoin(", ", TRUE, Text({1000, 2324}, "#,###")) and it applied the formatting to the whole array.   I was joining two arrays to each other.